# SSO/Auth between different sub-domains (w/ PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if I could use PHP to do SSO between two different sub-domains. (ex: parappawithfries.com and *.parappawithfries.com). My config is not like it should be, because I use cloudflare to point my subs to a different 000webhost website. I know I should just use infinityfree, but I don't get https:// and subdomains. Lots of issues, but it it could be fixed, that'd be great. ANYWAY, I was wondering if I could do something like this in HTML.

```
<script src="https://parappawithfries.com/user.js"></script>
```

and in user.js (in the NON sub-domain) needs to set a cookie with the user's PHPSESSID copied over by JS by basically printing it as a variable. Can I do that with JS, AJAX, jQuery, or any way possible without using anything other than PHP, HTML, JS, AJAX, or jQuery?

Ok, ok lemme edit im sorry. 
parappawithfries.com points to parappawithfries.000webhostapp.com.
It's subdomains don't point to a folder in parappawithfries.000webhostapp.com. it points to a DIFFERENT 000webhost site. Not a folder in parappawithfries.000webhostapp.com.

Oh yeah, btw, here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb81L.jpg

I need to edit... AGAIN (this is getting tiring)

I switched hosting from 000webhost to infinityfree and I got subdomains working. Time to see if it will work now...

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) you could set the Cookie for a specific domain (the root domain). Right?

Comment: Not with my config unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP if you `setcookie()` with a `$domain` parameter (e.g. parappawithfries.com), that cookie can be accessed by that domain and any subdomains.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

From there, you can make sure all your sites are set up to used a singular Memcached server, and they should all be able to share the same session(s).

Have a look at the below link for some details on setting this up.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-php-sessions-on-multiple-memcached-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: The subdomains point to a different website in 000webhosts database. Ex. parappawithfries.000webhostapp.com is parappawithfries.com right, but games.parappawithfries.com is pointing to poorgames2018.000webhostapp.com

Comment: What do you mean by "pointing to"? Does PHP see the hostname as games.parappawithfries.com? Try echoing the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. If PHP sees both domains correctly on both sites, Memcached should be happy.

Comment: It should work fine. A CNAME record isn't a forward, essentially it's just setting the A record to the same as the target of the CNAME.

Comment: Hmm... in your answer if I put in the start line of PHP code setcookie($domain = *.parappawithfries.com; "username=usernamecodehere") itll work with subdomains? I'll read the PHP manual to check.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got Infinityfree working WITH subdomains, https://, and MX records, so now I can use cookies correctly! https://imgur.com/9WGVkYf (only reason not secure is cause i just switched over from a different SSL user.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies cannot be shared across different domains; however, you could make use of another domain that would have the cookies and the authentication could take place there.

Comment: That's what I was asking! How can I get SSO/Auth (w/o Google) on my separate domains with just one?

Comment: I can make as many domains as needed. I'll probably make a sub-domain for SSO/Auth (https://login.parappawithfries.com). I'm wanting to do this not only for me because how annoying it is, but for visitors.

Comment: Then set the `$domain` argument in the [`setcookie`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function to your login domain.